# Can't get value form angular slider dynimically to calculate

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am very new to Angular js.

I am using rz-slider (https://jsfiddle.net/ValentinH/954eve2L/) to get value from a slider
Using the first example form the link

My HTML

```
<article>
  <rzslider
    rz-slider-model="ageofretirement.value"
    rz-slider-options="ageofretirement.options"
    >
  </rzslider>
</article>

<input type="number" name="required-fund-pm" id="pv" ng-model="pv" ng-change="change()" placeholder="Enter Amount">
```

My Controler

```
var app = angular.module('ChildPlanning', ['rzModule', 'ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, $modal)

  $scope.ageofretirement = {
   value: 20,
   options: {
    showSelectionBar: true,
    floor: 5,
    ceil: 35,
    showTicksValues: true
 }
};
$scope.pv = {
  value:0,
 };

   $scope.change = function(){
    $scope.annuity_future = $scope.pv * $scope.ageofretirement.value;
   };
 });
```

Output

```
<span>{{ annuity_future }}</span>
```

When I am dragging the slider the value of "ageofretirement.value" is not changing dynamically to be calculate

Comment: Could you give us a plunkr with your code ?

Comment: Here is the link to the full controller http://voguedirect.com/js/rzr-sliders/retirement.js
This is what i can give quickly

Comment: What does it happen if you add something like `$scope.onChange = function(){ console.log($scope.ageofretirement.value) }`  and on html code: `rz-slider-on-change="onChange()"` and then move slider?

Comment: Doesn't the ng-model need to match on the input and the rz-slider?  I thought that was how Angular handled linking controls on document load.

Answer (score 0):

Just used change function with ng-click on the element and it worked fine